# Is there a way to expand a dynamic memory array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, dynamic, expand

Is there a way to expand a dynamic memory array? like this:

```
int *a = new int[5];
*a = new int[2];
```

Is this legal?

Comment: What would you expect/want this code to do?

Comment: sure, that code is legal, it probably doesn't do what you expect though.

Comment: Use a `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: @Bwmat: actually, it's not legal, there's no implicit cast from `int *` to `int`.

Comment: In general you will have to copy the existing contents to a temporary variable, then create an array with the new expanded size and then initialize the new array with the values of your temporary variable. In the end you delete your temporary. This is for example how std::vector works internally.

Comment: ahh, you're right. I didn't really look too closely at it

Comment: I agree with @GMan, `std::vector<T>` provides the resizing without you having to worry. There is no standard construct to reallocate `new`-ed memory like with the `realloc()` function in C, so the typical way to do what you want to in C++ is to `new` more memory, copy the data from the old data block to the new one, and then `delete` the old pointer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot expand this type of a dynamic memory array. You can use `malloc` and `realloc` though if you need this facility but I would advice against that and suggest including `<vector>` and using `std::vector` instead. It has a `resize` method.

Also, what you described won't compile. The following will:

```
1: int *a = new int[5];
2: a = new int[2];
```

The above will allocate two memory blocks, neither of which will be destroyed. Second line will simply assign a new array to the same `int *a` pointer. When an allocated memory stops being referenced by any pointer, this is called a memory leak. The above code loses any reference to `new int[5]` and there is no way to free this memory to the operating system.

Although this is not a very practical example, there are multiple ways to resize an array/vector.
As it is usually practical to increase the array size, I will do just this:

```
{ // C++ vector on the stack (although internally vector uses memory from the heap)
    std::vector<int> a(1024);
    // do smth
    a.resize(4096); // note: this does not always reallocate
    // do smth else
}

{ // C++ everything on the heap
    std::vector<int> *a = new std::vector<int>(1024);
    // do smth
    a->resize(4096); // note: this does not always reallocate
    // do smth else
    delete a;
}

{ // C style
    int *a = (int*)malloc(1024*sizeof(int));
    // do smth
    a = realloc(a, 4096*sizeof(int));
    // do smth else
    free(a);
}
```

It is worth to note that `realloc` does not do anything smart. All it does is:

- Allocate new memory block `malloc`
- Copy data from old memory block to new memory block `memcpy`
- Free old memory block `free`
- Return new memory block

Comment: It's worth pointing out that `std::vector` will use copy/move operators, whereas any C-style version yields undefined behaviour for non-POD types.

Comment: What's the purpose of the "`// C++ everything on the heap`" section?

Comment: Just a different mean to achieve the same thing. Maybe it does not make much sense with later following it with `delete` but in general you sometimes use `new` to create vectors, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: @RushPL: Not often, no. I can't think of a time I have.

Comment: C++11 only recently added means to properly pass the underlying allocated pointer - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Rvalue_references_and_move_constructors In C++98 you would would often unnecessarily copy memory by passing such objects by value.

Comment: C Style has bug -- `malloc` requires `free`, not `delete`.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* certainly expand an array, but you need to take care of copying the contents and of freeing the old array (your code, apart from being incorrect syntax, shrinks the array, btw.).

Which is exactly how `std::vector` works, *just you don't have to care*.

So basically, having `int *a` already allocated, what needs to happen is something like:

```
{
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> d(a);
    a = new int[desired_new_size];
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < min_old_size_and_new_size; ++i)
        a[i] = d[i];
}
```

Note that strictly speaking "expanding" never *really* expands the array, but replaces it with another bigger one (that is true for any containers offering the same functionality too). But this is transparent to any code using the pointer later, nobody will know.

You should **never** use `realloc` (or any other C memory allocation functions) in combination with memory allocated or freed by `operator new` and `delete` (or `new[]` and `delete[]`) as pointed out above.
This *may work* (and usually will), but it's conceptually wrong, and it's pure luck (unknown implementation detail) if it does not crash.